# Apache: Unable to remove authentication prompt for subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4

My server is running Apache 2.4.18 with below config:

`/home/xxx/www/.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Digest
AuthName "Authenication Required"
AuthDigestProvider file
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htdigest
Require valid-user
```

`/home/xxx/www/share/.htaccess`:

```
Require all granted
```

I want password protection for all directories and files except for the `share` subdirectory. With the above configuration, a prompt for password authentication is shown when the user visits `http://my.site/share/`, although he can still see the content by cancling (or closing) the dialog.

What I want is to **remove the prompt for password authentication** for the `share` subdirectory. Is there anything wrong to my configuration?

Comment: Too late to help OP, I'm guessing, but in case someone stumbles on this question (like I did), I was eventually able to solve a similar problem when I realized the landing page for my unprotected directory was calling a javascript file from a password-protected directory. Putting those scripts in an unprotected directory eliminated the unwanted password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `AuthType None` in /home/xxx/www/share/.htaccess.

Comment: Tried. No luck.

Comment: Is the .htaccess file readable by Apache?

Comment: Apache has read and write permission of all files below /home/xxx/www/ directory. You mean this?

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

`Satisfy Any`

Allow from all

To:
`/home/xxx/www/share/.htacces`

Comment: Tried. No luck.

Comment: Add 'require none' to this.